# Adding and removing UIStackViews messing up my UIScrollView

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

[image]

[image]

Whenever I use the pickerview to switch views from Auto Rent to Schedule Rent it works perfectly. It is when I switch from Schedule Rent to Auto Rent that this black bar appears. I have attached the hierarchy of my content view. I thought it had to do with previous constraints added, so I remove a StackView whenever one view is chosen. For example, if Auto Rent is chosen, then I remove the StackView where the Schedule View is in:

```
//Holds Temp Stackviews
var stackViewHolder1: UIView?
var stackViewHolder2: UIView?
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    stackViewHolder1 = stackViewMain.arrangedSubviews[0]
    stackViewHolder2 = stackViewMain.arrangedSubviews[1]
 }

if txtRentType.text == "Auto Rent" {
   let tempView = stackViewHolder1
   let tempView1 = stackViewHolder2
   tempView!.isHidden = true
   stackViewMain.removeArrangedSubview(tempView!)
   if(tempView1!.isHidden == true){
       tempView1!.isHidden = false
       stackViewMain.addArrangedSubview(tempView1!)
   }
else{

      let tempView = stackViewHolder1
      let tempView1 = stackViewHolder2

      tempView1!.isHidden = true
      stackViewMain.removeArrangedSubview(tempView1!)

      if(tempView!.isHidden == true){
          tempView!.isHidden = false
          stackViewMain.addArrangedSubview(tempView!)
      }

    }
```

I have tried deleting one view and toggling only one view has being hidden and that removes the black bar issue. There is no constraint with the stackViews and Content View.

EDIT:
[image]

The screen highlighted is the scrollView. The one after is the contentView. UIWindow goes black in the back.

[image]

My Title Bar at the top ends up in the middle somehow.

Comment: Try placing your logic that hides the stack views inside a `UIView.animate` animations block

Comment: I have tried that before and it does not work.

Comment: Using the view debugger, is the black area part of the scrollview content, or is it the scrollview bottom that's moving up and exposing that area?

Comment: I will do the view debugger now, but i'm almost 100% it's the scrollview that is moving. I have a navigation bar on top and it disappears because the entire view is shifted upwards.

Comment: @GrahamPerks I edited my post to show the view debugger

Answer (score 0):

You can try to modify your stack distribution property

```
 stack.distribution = .equalCentering
```

After you won't need to use this:

```
 .removeArrangedSubview()
 .addArrangedSubview()
```

When you hide some view, the other view take all space of your stack, you don't need to update your constraints. You can try it on interface builder to see how it works.

Comment: The distribution does not change anything.

Answer (score 0):

are you pinning your scrollview and the content view to the bottom with constraints?

If the content view is a stack view you can pin it to the bottom as well with layout constraints and play with the content distribution.

Comment: I am not pinning it. This shouldn't be a response. Add this as a comment under my post.

Comment: Hey Eric, sure. by the way if you pin it to bottom of the superview it should fix your issue as I mentioned

Comment: But my content view is not a stack view

Comment: @EricAgredo pin it anyway, so it doesn't shrink

Comment: I did. You're saying to give a bottom anchor constraint to content view of 0 right? Doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use remove/Add arranged subviews.

when hiding a view in a stackView its automatically removed.

so i think you can just hide or show the stackViewMain.subviews[0] o stackViewMain.subviews[1]

i'm with objc maybe i do a mistake but it would be something like this :

```
if txtRentType.text == "Auto Rent" {
       stackViewMain.arrangedSubviews[0].isHidden = true;
       stackViewMain.arrangedSubviews[1].isHidden = false;
}else{
       stackViewMain.arrangedSubviews[1].isHidden = true;
       stackViewMain.arrangedSubviews[0].isHidden = false;
}
```